# Is there a reason why http response is different from the site and code output?

Tags: python, http, azure-language-understanding

I get a http response using Python by executing the following code:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')

conn.request("GET", "/something/somethig")
response = conn.getresponse()
#data = response.read()
data =json.load(response)
print(data)
```

The results show a list of API results.

But they are different from the one that is executed and when I manually access the `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/something/something` website.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: `httplib` doesn't evaluate JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that are different between a request in a script and a request in a browser. For one, your script will not execute any associated JavaScript from the page. Second, the header of your http request includes details of the requesting client.

For example for a REST interface, a server may return the plainest JSON to an application request and return a formatted page for a browser request.

In Chrome, you can open the developer tools with "..."->"More Tools"->"Developer Tools", and with that open, you can open all of your requests and see the headers:

[image: Chrome view of request headers]

There is a similar function in Firefox for looking at headers. Click the hamburger->"Developer"->"Web Console". Under "Net" you can filter for requests. Click a request to see the details.

[image]

For POST commands, also look at the body of the request.

Finally, last week, I was trying to automate a POST command in Java, and I had some difficulty in doing so. A colleague was able to make the call with the `curl` command, and that gave me enough clues about the critical parameters. So I recommend trying `curl` which can help distinguish critical parameters from accidental ones, or at least to look at the problem from another angle.

Comment: But when I give an input the response is different. In the webpage it outputs a list that has a specific array filled with items, while in a script output that specific array is empty. I don't think this has anything to do with formats.

Comment: Log your application request to the console and use the developer tools in the browser to view the browser request.

Comment: Also, if you have the `curl` command available, try the same request with that.